# Two maven builds, same code, same libs, but one war fails with HibernateException

Tags: java, maven

Same JDK (1.8). Same Maven (v. 3.0). Both compile with Jenkins (and both installed by Jenkins). Everything works when building, but when deployed one of the `war` fails. A `@Scheduled` task fails because of loosing Hibernate session (stack below). The only difference is that one `war` is built on CentOS and the other on Ubuntu (the one built on Ubuntu fails).

What I should be looking for? Some system components difference? Is there something like uninitialized variables in Java that work like in C (were you can get different initial values depending on build type).

```
2021-10-11 16:40:00.0003 ERROR: scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:993)
        at com.example.dao.SettingDAO.getByKeys(SettingDAO.java:139)
```

Just as a note -- I already compared files inside the `war` file. Everything is exactly the same. Seems like just one jar is different. But just in terms of metadata, because files inside the jar are also exactly the same, except for paths in `builddef.lst` and date in `pom.properties`.

PS: The `war` itself runs in exactly the same environment. It is deployed via Jenkins so exactly the same procedure each time. The environment is Tomcat 7, JDK7, PG10.

Comment: What do you mean by Maven 3.0?

Comment: You should check if you run your code in the same manner in both case, eg: 1) you use the same version of Java 2) same version of Maven 3) same version of Maven Plugins 4) you fork - or not fork - process in both case.

Comment: Check the order tests were executed in on the two machines. There is usually no guarantee that tests will run in a particular order, unless the test developer explicitly defines that somehow (depends on test framework). You may be running into a case where one test inadvertently depends on the results of another.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I meant Apache Maven version 3.0.4 if that matters. But the problem seem to occur with Maven 3.3.9 as well. All is installed automatically via Jenkins, so should be the same.

Comment: It actually all runs in the same Tomcat. Same machine. And the problem (Exception) occurs when `war` is deployed. Not when building.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` on the same method. Extremely weird that it worked when built on one Linux machine and not on the other (even when running on exactly the same machine.

So the solution was to create a ~proxy class with `@Scheduled` on methods which just call `@Transactional` method. E.g:

```
@Service
public class SchedulerProxyService {
// ...
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.loanNotifyReturns}")
    public void loanNotifyReturns() throws LoanScheduleFailedException {
        loanService.notifyReturns();
    }
}
```